# Can't access Jekyll port 4000

Tags: content-management-system, webserver, port, jekyll

I'm trying to install [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) on my Mac through terminal. I created a new website with the following command:

```
jekyll new blog
```

When I go to the directory in finder, I see the site has actually been created, but then when I try to access it at http://localhost:4000/ I get a "This site can’t be reached" error message. I use MAMP if that is at all relevant. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Answer is in the documentation http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

`jekyll new blog` creates the standard Jekyll template. After running the `new` command, you'll have to start the server. To do this, change into the folder:

```
cd blog
```

Install the dependencies (Jekyll 3+):

```
bundle install
```

Run the server:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Then open up a browser at http://localhost:4000/

You'll have to run `bundle install` each time you add a plugin, but otherwise to get the server started again you'll only need the last command.